# Getting downvotes on the main site, despite improvement attempts

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm still getting downvotes on a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367103/swift-macos-how-to-choose-the-components-that-handle-serialization-notificatio) that I thought I had improved considerably after feedback from commenters. But although the downvoters aren't commenting, they're still downvoting. The question is totally within the guidelines -- I try to be careful about that on the SO sites. So, does anyone have a wild guess why I'm getting downvotes?

Comment: Your efforts to improve the question are appreciated, but the core question (the bold part) is off topic. It's overly broad, and it's polling for people's opinions. That's the first thing you need to change, the question should be focused on an actual problem you are facing. Explain what you have already tried, and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Also, there's a lot of random noise in your question. Please avoid things like edit notices - we don't need you to tell us the question has been edited, there's a public revision history. We also don't need meta-commentary like "I've been on an epic journey that you don't want to hear about". If we don't need to hear about it, then it shouldn't be mentioning it at all. Please remove everything that isn't absolutely necessary - your question is already long enough without the meta-commentary.

Comment: I've tried [reducing some of the noise](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/367103/25936) (feel free to roll back my edit if you don't agree with it). Hopefully, we'll also find a way to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: @yannis Thanks very much. Anything to stop the downvotes at this point. I've lost more SE reputation in the last couple of days than I have in the ten years I've been using the sites. I'm worried that with the question permanently out there, I'll eventually get so many downvotes that I won't be able to participate on the site any more.

Comment: @yannis One thing: please help me to understand your suggestion that I "explain what I've already tried". I thought the paragraph starting with "I've tried a model of simple JSON" did that pretty well. Is there something more that I can add to that, to indicate what I've tried? Or is it in an ok state after your edits?

Comment: @yannis Ok, two things. I thought that a question about what's typical, or nearly typical, in the community was a fact-based question that could be answered with facts, like "most people use Core Data and the Zippo Discount notification services for the tasks you're talking about." That would be a statement of fact, or at least an educated guess at facts. Does that fall under "opinion-based"? I'm not complaining; I just want to make it a more effective question, and not repeat this situation ever again.

Comment: I highly doubt there's research that shows what most people use. But even if there is, "most people use foo" is an answer to a poll, not a solution to an actual, practical software development problem. For all you know, the more popular / typical solution may be completely incompatible with your requirements.

Comment: @yannis Ok, I think I get it now. Again, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: It's not you. My posts are getting downvoted almost immediately, multiple times. They usually are deleted in about a day. Doesn't matter what I write or rewrite. I'm not going to jump to any conclusions but if I had to guess  some of the people on this site hate their lives and they are taking it out on the users. Whatever the reason it's happened enough that I'm avoiding this site as much as possible. I've had two questions deleted in the last few days.

Comment: Related. These sites end up enraging people.  https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6878/migrating-crap-to-so-really-programmers/6879#6879.